# Showing a dialog with BlocListener

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management, flutter-bloc

I have 2 textFields that have a gesture detector and on tap of the gesture detector, I open an AlertDialog using the BlocListener widget.

```
Widget _getSourceAndOriginTextField(String hintText, controller) {
    final portsCubit = BlocProvider.of<PortsCubit>(context);
    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller..text = "",
      readOnly: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                portsCubit.getAllPorts();
              },
              child: BlocListener<PortsCubit, PortsState>(
                listenWhen: (previous, current) => previous != current,
                listener: (context, state) async {
                  if (state is PortsLoadedState) {
                    await showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
                              value: portsCubit,
                              child: PortsDialog(state.portsList),
                            ));
                  }
                },
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/svg/chevron_down_icon.svg',
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                  height: 10,
                  width: 18,
                ),
              )),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              style: BorderStyle.solid,
              width: 1,
            ),
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
          ),
          filled: true,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          hintText: hintText,
          hintStyle: AppStyle.hintStyle),
    );
  }
```

This method above which returns a TextField is being used inside the form to display two textfields.

```
Form(
    children:[_getSourceAndOriginTextField('Origin',controller),
    SizedBox(height:10),
    _getSourceAndOriginTextField('Origin',controller)])
```

When I tap on one of the textfields the state changes and the dialog opens but the dialog is displayed twice. What am I missing here?

Following are the images for reference, any help will be appreciated.

[TextField inside the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKUKv.jpg).

[The AlertDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU2nE.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have 2 textFields

and

> This method above which returns a TextField is being used inside the form to display two textfields.

basically explains your problem. Since you are executing `_getSourceAndOriginTextField()` twice, you also create the `BlocListener<PortsCubit, PortsState>(...)` twice. Thus, when the `PortsCubit` state changes to `PortsLoadedState`, both listeners trigger the `showDialog` function.

What you can do is lift the `BlocListener` and wrap the `Form` with it. This way you will have only a single listener that could open the dialog:

```
BlocListener<PortsCubit, PortsState>(
  listenWhen: (previous, current) => previous != current,
  listener: (context, state) async {
    if (state is PortsLoadedState) {
      await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
          value: portsCubit,
          child: PortsDialog(state.portsList),
      ));
  },
  child: Form(
    children:[_getSourceAndOriginTextField('Origin',controller),
    SizedBox(height:10),
    _getSourceAndOriginTextField('Origin',controller)]) 
},
```

Comment: Great to hear that! Do not forget to mark the answer as correct - maybe it will help the others, too.